# How to create an ultra-secure connection between two clients with xor?

Tags: encryption, algorithm-design, protocol-design

At work, I was asked to create **ultra-secure** connection over lan between two computers. It will be some kind of messager. I have a bunch of same random data in them(near 100mb). Also I can start a server with same data. I will not have access to clients, so I will not be able to update the random data on them.

Can I use XOR?

Comment: Welcome to crypto.stackexchange - Unfortunately this question is way too broad; We require questions that can precisely be answered, rather than discussed. Have you considered TLS?

Comment: @EllaRose, Thanks. I'm just trying to make question more relevant (and 
follow the rules).

Comment: Pretty much anything you do with a computer will involve XOR, including using TLS.  Could you be more specific about what your security criteria are?  If you're thinking of using a one-time pad—which TLS does internally for most common cipher suites, generated by a stream cipher much faster and more reliably and safer than your 100 MB of random data likely are, and not limited to transmitting 100 MB on the network—note that a mere one-time pad will do nothing to prevent forgery, which TLS does prevent as long as the endpoints can authenticate each other, _e.g._ with certificates.

Comment: @SqueamishOssifrage I was asked to make algorithm super simple. Something like handwrite realisation. So if I will not find the way, I'll use your and Ella Rose advice. Thanks!

Comment: What is handwrite realization?  If you mean you're going to do this by hand…why are there computers involved?  To make this question answerable, you need to be more specific about what your goals and engineering constraints are; qualifiers like ‘ultra-secure’ don't mean anything.

Comment: @SqueamishOssifrage, yup, thinking how to formulate question better:)

Comment: @SqueamishOssifrage That's not the definition of a OTP.

Comment: Yes, you can use XOR, lookup OTP. Note that you still need to keep the key stream (the 100 mb file) secure, keep both sides synced somehow and probably remember that an OTP doesn't provide message integrity or authentication (which is, therefore, not something I'd call ultra-secure). However, it is undoubtedly what is meant.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes, tnanks for your comment! Do you have any ideas how to keep key stream fresh (if I will not have access to clients)? Because OTP require 
physical key distribution.

Comment: Yes, you forget about OTP and use an authenticated stream cipher. There are various ways of keeping your keys fresh after that; ratchets, redoing the key agreement or complete handshake, deriving new keys from a master key and so on.